# unable to read the another web site content using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hi team actual my scope in this is, i want to fetch the content from this URL.

i want to implement this in mobile application.

[INDIAN EMU TRAIN TIMEING](http://erail.in/suburban/chennai/trains-between-stations/AIP-Attippattu-to-PON-Ponneri/?filter=2%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C7%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C)

when run the browser, i am getting error alert message only, how to read another site content using jquery. please advise.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function () {alert("test");
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://google.com',
            type: 'GET',
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
            },
            success: function(res) {
               alert(res);
            }
        });  
      });
   </script>
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/IYePazi/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can't create XMLHttpRequest in this way.
**Same-origin policy** prevents from this.

Take a look: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy.

If you want to get data from google.com as in your example - you need to use server-side as proxy 
and load data via your server-side.

Anyway, even if you use server-side - it's does not guarantee response from google - you will need to simulate browser request and this is the subject of separate question

Comment: php:  file_get_content also unable to read the google.com content. any valuable suggestion for this ?

Comment: @Bharanikumar php is capable of reading whatever the remote website gives you, even if it doesn't give you what you expect.

Comment: Kevin B just now i added some more input in my quyestion, i want fetch the some details from other site. can u just take a look into that.

Answer (score 0):

We Can not read the content of other website using Jquery as Browser suppress the cross domain information. u need to have server side support for that. If u want to still try then try this

format.jsonp { render json: results, callback: params[:callback]}

I read somewhere, that above code works. but it never worked for me.